# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dispose

I've seen this question asked a million times, but every single suggestion I've encountered I already seem to have covered.

I have entity framework in my MVC solution, and I have a 'repository' which attempts to retrieve a collection of `MyObject`s:

```
public static List<MyObject> GetMyObjects()
{
   using (var context = new MyEntities())
   {
       return context.MyObjects.Include("Contact").OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).ToList();
   }
}
```

I call this method as part of a controller action which attempts to serialize it:

```
public JsonResult All()
{
   return Json(MyRepository.GetMyObjects(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And I get the following error:

**The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.**

I don't know where to turn on this one, I appreciate entity framework 'lazy-loads' relational data sets if and when they're needed, and I appreciate attempting to serialize the whole collection would indeed attempt to load these (outside of the using statement), but I have the 'Include' there.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried the 'include', I've also ensured no other associations are part of the `MyObject` class (i.e. I have no other `Include()`s to write).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid this you have some options.Don't declare your navigation properties as `virtual` or disable **Lazy Loading** behavior on your context. Lazy loading is enable by default and is achieved by creating instances of derived proxy types and then overriding `virtual` properties to add the loading hook. So, if you want to work with a serializer I recommend you turn off lazy loading:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public YourContext() 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```

These links can help you to understand better what I explain in my answer:

- [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)
- [Requirements for Creating POCO Proxies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx)

If you remove the `virtual` keyword from your navigation properties, the POCO entity not meet the requirements described in the second link, so, EF won't create a proxy class to lazy load your navigation properties. But if you disabled lazy loading, even when your navigation properties are `virtual`, they won't be loaded in any entity. It's good idea disable lazy loading when you are using a serializer. Most serializers work by accessing each property on an instance of a type.

As a third option you could use the [JsonIgnore](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) attribute on your navigation properties that you don't want to be serialized as part of your entity, but as I said before, the best option is disable lazy loading.

Comment: Brilliant! I'm not at home at the moment to be able to try your solution, but I'm hopeful. I'll give it a go and feedback when it's tried and tested. Thanks again. +1.

Comment: Glad for having helped you ;)

Comment: Besides this I had to clone the entity as I was using two context one for online and another for offline db

Answer (score 0):

When you use Include and using Lazy loading, and wrap the dbContext in a Using statement, then once it tries to get the linked objects, the dbContext is already disposed.
You can try eager loading of the navigation property like this:

```
IQueryable<MyObjects> query = db.MyObjects.Include(m => m.Contact);
```

Or you could take out the Using statement, as it is limiting your lazy loading...

Comment: If I take out the using statement I'm surely leaving unnecessary work to the garbage collector? I never like to not dispose of something that implement IDisposable. I may be wrong?

Comment: @JayMee Then you need to use the eager loading(as shown in my code here) if you want to keep the "Using" statement...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved like below;

I created a new object and put the values I am gonna use after getting object from db.

Example Code:

```
 var listFromDb= db.XTable.Where(x => x.Id > 5).ToList();

 var list = new List<Package>();

 foreach (var item in listFromDb)
 {
     var a = new Package()
     {
          AccountNo = item.AccountNo,
          CreateDate = item.CreateDate,
          IsResultCreated = item.IsResultCreated,
        };
        list.Add(a);
      }
```