# Entity Framework model to Json Result

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I confused with error that Action returns me. I have a code in my manager:

```
public class AddressesManager
    {

     private SiteDBEntities entityContext;

     public Addresses GetAddress(short id)
            {
                entityContext = new SiteDBEntities();
                var addressList = entityContext.Addresses.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                entityContext.Dispose();
                return addressList;
            }
}
```

And action that call this function:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoadAddress(short id)
        {
            AddressesManager mngr = new AddressesManager();
            Addresses address = mngr.GetAddress(id);
            return new JsonResult() { Data = address };
        }
```

And jquery code wich call thit action:

```
$.post("/Cart/LoadAddress", { id: id })
         .success(function (data) {

             console.log(data);
         })
    .fail(function (e) { console.log(e) });
```

Action is running, but i always getting 500 error whit this code:

***The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.***

As i understood the problem is with *entityContext* , but why this happens? I already executed data from DB and I don't need connection anymore...

**EDIT:**

Thit is my Address model. It autogenerated by EF:

```
public partial class Addresses
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Warehouse { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public short DeliveryType { get; set; }
        public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual DeliveryType DeliveryType1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I checked data in address variable - everything OK and data present here

Comment: this error happens because the Addresses Class has some virtual properties, and it is Converted to JSON , it wants to get those virtual properties too.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is it. So what is the way to avoid this error? Manualy map the model?

Comment: Try this `entityContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: Agreed with @Arvin, json serializer is trying to access to some navigation property, and due to that, lazy loading is getting triggered. Check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744530/the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-longer-be-used

Comment: Another option is create a custom class with only the data you need in your view, also called as DTO or ViewModel class. I suggest to use that practice in combination with Automapper.

Comment: @octavioccl o , man you just give me an answer for question that was in my head for a long time - "what is hte difference between DTO and EF model. Isn't it the same thing?"

Comment: @dantey89 try adding [ScriptIgnore] or [JsonIgnore] Attribite to virtual properties.

Comment: @Arvin the problem that Addresses model generating from DB , and it will override my attribyte after each update

Comment: @dantey89 in that case you can edit the Model.tt file which generate the Addresses class and the other class from DB.

Comment: @dantey89, a Model is the representation what you really have in your data source, in other words, represents your data schema. A DTO is used when you want to customize what you need to send to the client application or your UI. Not always you need to send all the data you have in a row to a view. Usually those custom classes are created in your business layer.

Comment: @octavioccl I thought "why do I need DTO wich is a dublicate of EF model. For 3-layer application it's usefull but in my case when I  declined 3-layer application I can use EF models and escape extra code"

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because your `Address` class has 2 virtual properties: `DeliveryType1` and `Users`.

When you convert your `address` to JSON, it will try to access those virtual properties. However, at that time, your context are disposed already.

To avoid this problem, you shouldn't return the EF auto-generated class directly. Instead, create a DTO object (Data Transfer Object) containing only some fields you need, map it with the EF object, and return it. For example:

```
public class AddressesDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Warehouse { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public short DeliveryType { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, map it:

```
public Addresses GetAddress(short id)
{
    entityContext = new SiteDBEntities();
    var addressList = entityContext.Addresses.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    // Create DTO object
    AddressesDTO address = new AddressesDTO();

    // Map it
    address.Id = addressList.Id;
    address.Title = addressList.Title
    // Go on, it's quite long...

    entityContext.Dispose();
    return address;
}
```

However, as you can see, the mapping process is very boring. A better way is using [Automapper](http://automapper.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your entity data model then I suggest you to take a look to my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744530/the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-longer-be-used).

Now, what I would do is create a DTO to get only the data you need to pass to your View, like was proposed by @AnhTriet. To avoid map by yourself each property every time you need to project your query to your DTO, I suggest to use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/). Let me show you how would be your solution if you decide to use it:

```
public class AddressesManager
{
    public Addresses GetAddress(short id)
    {

        using(var entityContext = new SiteDBEntities())
        {
            var address = entityContext.Addresses
                                       .Where(a => a.Id == id)
                                       .ProjectTo<AddressDTO>()
                                       .FirstOrDefault();
            return address;
        }
    }
}
```

About [ProjectTo](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) extension method.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I currently study in courses and I heard from guys from my group about bad performance when they  used Automaper. So they decide to use custom mapping.

Comment: Your comment about DTO was usefulest thing for me. Now I can understand program architecture more clear

Comment: You're welcome ;). About Automapper, I have to say at least in my case I haven't had that kind of issue. But I think all depends in the way you create your queries because at the end are translated to SQL, and if you do something inefficient in your Linq queries  or map unnecessary data, of course that will affect your performance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a navigation (child) property in your Address class? I get the feeling that you're trying to access this child property after the DbContext has been disposed of, as child properties are lazy-loaded by default.

Can you post the code of your Address model?

Comment: Is a good practice to use EFcontext.Dispose() in destructor of my manager to avoid porblem wiht lazy loading?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add attribute [JsonIgnore] to virtual properties of Addresses Class.

```
class Addresses
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Something Something { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Addresses should be lazy-loaded in your case. So you are trying to access disposed data and Entity Framework tries to use disposed context and that gives an exception.

Maybe you need to attach your addressList to current context in order to enable lazy-loading

```
var addressList = entityContext.Addresses.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
entityContext.Addresses.Attach(addressList);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are returning a json record in MVC you need to add AllowGet like so in your controller:

```
return Json(new { data= address }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

With this in place you should be fine.